# Type not an object in Chrome's debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've written a standalone javascript proof of concept which I'm now trying to integrate into a larger app. I'm having some problems with methods not being found on a certain object in the new environment, even though I'm instantiating it in the same way.

When I look at the object I've created in both apps in Chrome's debugger, the one that works is marked as type 'Object' and the one that doesn't is marked as type 'a' (whatever that is!) That seems to be the only difference, but can anyone suggest what 'a' is and what might be causing this to happen?

Comment: Some code will be really helpful.

Comment: Gambling is on, I'd say 'a' is the result of a packed script :)